# Where's Kile's dictionary now?

Tags: dictionary, kile

I'm on Ububtu 20.04, running Kile 2.9.93. Does anyone know where the dictionary is stored? Every now and then I need to change system and then I must add the same exceptions by hand over and over again.

I saw this question from 2010:

[Where is Kile's dictionary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12579/where-is-kiles-dictionary/46796#46796)

however, the files I have in .config/enchant/ are all empty. Searching for *dic was also not enlightening. Maybe something changed in the meantime?

Does anyone have other ideas? Can I find kile's inner settings somewhere?

Comment: What does `dpkg -L kile` tell you?

Comment: Good idea!
So, I see the bin file, a libkdeinit5_kile.so in /usr/lib/ and lots of files in /usr/share/.
Among them is config.kcfg/kile.kcfg, which contains many options but none of them seems obviously related with the spellcheck.
Another file of interest is kile/kilestdtools.rc, but I didn't have luck there either.
What should I be looking for?

Comment: Personally I added `AVerySpecificPattern` to Kile dictionary, then I ran `sudo grep -rI 'AVerySpecificPattern' ~/ 2> /dev/null` and found out `~/.hunspell_fr_FR` (I configured to some extent Kile to French).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone says, the answer depends on the dictionary system in use. It appears that my installation of Ubuntu 20.04 uses aspell: I found the list of added words in a file called `.aspell.en.pws` in my home folder.

I was actually looking for something like it, I don't know why it took me so long to find it (I only noticed it running `sudo find -name "*spell*"` from the root folder). I am answering this question, just in case someone like me is also searching for it.